# Can I copy.copy a PhotoImage on python?

Tags: image, python-3.x, tkinter, copy

I need to create a copy of an image.
Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
copy.cpoy(PhotoImage(width=imgWidth, height=imgHeight))
```

Comment: You might need to explain what the problem with your code is.

Comment: I don't know python but `cpoy` sure doesn't look right to me

Answer (score 0):

Instances of `PhotoImage` have a `copy` method which returns a copy of the image.

```
img = PhotoImage(...)
copy = img.copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

A PhotoImage object doesn't have a copy() method. But if you loaded an image from storage with Image.open() then the returned object does have a copy member.

```
image = (Image.open(f"\Graphics\\token_shoe.png"))
cpy = image.copy()
imgobj = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
imgobj_copy = ImageTk.PhotoImage(cpy)
```

You have two copies of suitable for tk widgets.

Comment: `tkinter.PhotoImage` does have a `copy()` function. OP does not say `PhotoImage` is from `Pillow` module.